# Java JFileChooser unable to detect foreign languages

Tags: java, macos, swing, locale, jfilechooser

In my application, the user chooses a file for which `JFileChooser` is used. It so happens that if the folder name is in some other language, then it doesn't detect that folder.

For example: On the desktop, if the folder name is `spillet sitt på er helt` (norweigian), then all the folders are displayed by the JFileChooser apart from the above folder mentioned. How do I deal with this issue?

PS: It turns out that this issue is only on Mac. Works well on windows.

Comment: What is your operating system? Perhaps Java expects UTF-8 while the folder name is in a different encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue (find here the [bug status report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7193966)).

It seems it has been eventually fixed in 7u10, 7u11 and 7u12+ updates.

For these updates haven't been oficially released, if you can't wait, you can download the Developers Review Releases at [java.net](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html).